# Link failure while building JEPP : cannot open input file 'dl.lib'

Tags: python, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, python-2.7, jepp

I am tried to build/install [jepp](http://jepp.sourceforge.net/usage.html) using VS 2012, and received the following link failure

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'dl.lib'
```

I tried searching the net but cannot find any conclusive reference which would tell me what I might be missing

I was wondering if this lib may be related to [dl — Call C functions in shared objects](http://docs.python.org/2/library/dl.html), because this package also seems to be missing from my import library

My Current Configuration

- OS: Win 7 X64
- Py: 2.7 X64
- Jepp - Compiled with VC11 X64

Apart from the standard Python Libraries, the following packages are also installed

- pywin32==218
- pywinauto==0.4.1

Please let me know, what I might be missing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually there is nothing like dl.dll. If you refer the link page in the manual, the now deprecated module is for Unix and there is no such module for windows.
The problem is actually in a jep module where the functionality did not considered windows

The original code in jep\commands\python.py

```
def get_python_libs():
    """
    Get the shared library names for embedding jep.

    See python-config
    """
    return ['python' + sysconfig.get_config_var('VERSION'), 'dl']
```

should have been written as (or something equivalent)

```
def get_python_libs():
    """
    Get the shared library names for embedding jep.

    See python-config
    """
    if is_win():
        return ['python' + sysconfig.get_config_var('VERSION')]
    else:
        return ['python' + sysconfig.get_config_var('VERSION'), 'dl']
```